# htaccess use OR condition in RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking for a solution where i can define the muliple match statement whitin the single RewriteCond statement,

The scenario is i want to redirect to home page if any of this string comes in the url:
`/it/, /de/, /fr/`

I tried to wrote it like this:

1. This is throwing `SERVER ERROR`:

   ```
   RewriteCond ^(/it/ | /de/ | /fr/ )
   RewriteRule 'myhomepageurl'
   ```
2. I also tried this way too:

   ```
   RewriteCond /it/ [OR]
   RewriteCond /de/ [OR]
   RewriteCond /fr/ [OR]
   RewriteRule 'myhomepageurl'
   ```

This was giving unexpected results page loding infinite and admin was blocked. So i finaly took this way:

```
RewriteCond /it/
RewriteRule 'myhomepageurl'

RewriteCond /de/
RewriteRule 'myhomepageurl'

RewriteCond /fr/
RewriteRule 'myhomepageurl'
```

I am just curious about the single statement that can do this in single shot.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Your first example is failing because of the spaces; a better regex would be something like

```
RewriteCond ^/(it|de|fr)/
RewriteRule 'myhomepageurl'
```

Either way, you should read [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) and use one of the simpler forms suggested there, e.g.

```
RedirectMatch /(it|de|fr)/ /myhomepageurl
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(en|de|it)/
RewriteRule .* myhomepageurl [R=301,L]
```